# Measures which are absolutely continuous with respect to a Riemannian measure

Tags: measure-theory, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a oriented connected Riemannian manifold (but not necessarily compact). Let $\omega_g$ denote the volume form on $M$ determined by $g$, and let $m_g$ denote the probability measure on $M$ defined by

$
m_g(\phi) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(M,g)}\int_M \phi \omega_g,
$

where $m_g$ is thought of as a positive linear functional on the space of continuous bounded functions on $M$.

If $n$ is another probability measure on $M$ then *if* $n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m_g$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $a = \frac{dn}{dm_g} $ is a well defined function in $L^1(M,m_g)$.

**My question is the following:** Is there a nice way to describe the subset of the space $P(M)$ of probability measures on $M$ which are absolutely continuous with respect to my given $m_g$?

The book I am reading seems to imply that *every* $n \in P(M)$ has a well-defined Radon-Nikodym derivative $a = \frac{dn}{dm_g} $. But this seems false to me (at least, I think it's false for $M = \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Why do you think it's false? It seems to me that this is exactly Radon-Nikodym's theorem.

Comment: But not every measure is absolutely continuous with respect to a given one?

Comment: Of course not, the Dirac delta being the usual counterexample. But this does not void the validity of the statement in your book: prob measures *that are absolutely continuous* with respect to $m_g$ are given by integration against a nonnegative integrable function. This is Radon-Nikodym's theorem.

Comment: Yes, so my question is, is there a "nice way" to describe the subset of probability measures that are absolutely continuous with respect to a given one.

Comment: Ok. But I don't think you can find anything nicer than the definition ($\mu$ is abs cont with respect to $\nu$ iff $\nu(E)=0$ implies $\mu(E)=0$).

Comment: One nice description is just $P(M)=\{f \,d m_g \mid f\in L^1(m_g) \text{ with } f\geq 0 \text{ and } \int f \,d m_g =1\}$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I think you shall post this as an answer. Perhaps also worth pointing out, that it does not matter whether $m_g$ is generated by the volume form, or in fact any $\sigma$-finite measure on any measurable space.

Answer (score 0):

As I already pointed out in the comments, one nice way of expressing the set $P$ of probability measures that are absolutely continuous with respect to some $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ is

$$
P = \bigg\{f \, d\mu \, \mid \, f\in L^1(\mu) \text{ with } f \geq 0\text{ and } \int f \, d\mu =1 \bigg\}.
$$

The inclusion "$\supset$" is immediate and the reverse inclusion is a consequence of the Radon Nikodym theorem.

Because manifolds are second countable and since the measure generated by the volume form is locally finite, the measure $m_g$ is $\sigma$-finite. Hence, the above identity also holds for $d\mu = dm_g$.